# Are all Verizon iPhone 5S are GSM Unlocked globally?

Tags: network, iphone

I am getting an iPhone 5S, Verizon version from USA and I plan to use it in India (on a GSM network). I read that Verizon iPhone 5S are GSM unlocked globally and can be used anywhere in the World. Is that true? Is that for only select model numbers/batch? Or does it apply to all Verizon iPhone 5S?

PS - I will be not using 4G/LTE, only 2G/3G is enough.

Answer (score 1):

The SIM slot on all Verizon 4G LTE devices is unlocked from the time of purchase.

Comment: So that's a yes and I can use it in India without any issues?

Comment: "Without issues" may be another story ;) but it's a yes, the SIM slot is not locked to Verizon.

Comment: what do you mean by first sentence?

Comment: I mean that there is always a possibility of problems, no matter how carefully you plan for something.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will work. Just pop in a GSM SIM card. Even 2G and 3G will work without any flaw. I myself using one 5S 16GB.